# How to save a string in SQL Server as SqlDateType by using Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

How to save a string in SQL Server as `SqlDateType` by using Visual Studio 2013? My string which I want to save is `1996-25-04`. I am working with C#.

I have tried this as far

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=sms;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pass");
con.Open();

string sql = "  insert into Staff_Management values( '" + TM_Add_BirthDate.Value.ToString() + "' ";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully");
```

Comment: And what have you tried? We´re not doing your work, which is *thinking*. We may help you, if you are stuck at some specific point.

Comment: Write the codes that you tried.

Comment: I would write some C# code to do it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should ***NEVER EVER*** concatenate together your SQL statements like this! This opens all doors to SQL injection attacks - and causes trouble with string and date values.

Try this code instead - using a **parametrized query**:

```
// define the query - and I'd recommend to always define the name of the columns you're inserting into
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Staff_Management(name-of-column-here) VALUES (@Birthdate);";

// define connection and command
// also: do **NOT** use the `sa` user for your production code! 
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=sms;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pass"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    // add the parameter - and use the proper datatype - don't convert all dates to strings all the time!
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Birthdate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = TM_Add_Birthdate.Value;

    // open connection, execute INSERT query, close connection - done
    con.Open(); 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully");
}
```